# Javascript Remoting Timeout

Tags: javascript-remoting

We have a group of employees at a remote site who recently began experiencing problem with timeouts with Javascript remoting. When I test the page from our main office (or my house), it works fine. Could this be due to something strange with the internet or network at that remote site?

Currently the timeout is set to 30 seconds. I am going to try and increase it to the maximum and see if that helps.

Has anyone else seen timeouts from one location and not another? Any tips on troubleshooting or corrective action to take?

Comment: Does it happen occasionally or it happens constantly when trying to access from the other location?

Comment: Can you dump the full request and response HTTP headers of a successful request? Are they on a dumb proxy that is doing jiggery pokery with the client IP address? Or other factors visible to the Salesforce cache/session layers?

Comment: I haven't been able to get onto their network yet. Was hoping you guys might be able to point out some things to check once I get access. They say it happens constantly for the last 2 days. Makes me think something happened on their network.

Comment: There might be some issues with SF too during this time before updating the instances. Some people are also able to deploy classes which are already scheduled when they shouldn't be able to...

Answer (score 1):

After some troubleshooting today, it turns out the location was a red herring. The problem was that my remoting call was calling a method that did a call out to another system. The javascript remoting timeout was shorter than the callout from Apex. The users with the problem were requesting data that took a long time to retrieve. When we tested, the callout has already been done once and the web service had cached the response so a second try was much faster.

Moral to this story: when mixing Javascript Remoting with callouts, check your timeout values closely and make sure the web service you are calling can handle the load.